# Update Data flow connection details for a given Power BI report Dataset

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I want get the Connection details against a Power BI report Dataset. Here, please note that my Datasource for Power Bi report Dataset is Dataflow.

$PbiDataSourcesObject = (Get-PowerBIDatasource -DatasetId $DatasetId)
$PbiDataSourcesObject.ConnectionDetails

Output is coming as Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Shared.DatasourceConnectionDetails

Now, I need to update my Dataflow connection to a different workspace once i have the connection.

$PbiDataSourcesObject = (Get-PowerBIDatasource -DatasetId $DatasetId)
$PbiDataSourcesObject.ConnectionDetails

Output is coming as Microsoft.PowerBI.Common.Api.Shared.DatasourceConnectionDetails